# Difficulties rendering canvas pie chart when using forEach

Tags: for-loop, foreach, html5-canvas, draw

I am trying to draw canvas pie chart "slices" from a data set using vanilla JavaScript. The idea is to use the `forEach` method to run through each data value property to get the "startAngle" and "endAngle" of each slice.

The slices are drawn fine when when I use a regular `for` loop to run through my data. However, when I take the same code and use the forEach method on the data, the slices are not drawn.

The full example of my pie chart and the issue I am dealing with can be found at this JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/JonDWesley/okvbgau6/328/

Here is the code that works to loop through my data and draw a pie chart "slice":

```
let sliceStartAngle = 0;
for (var n = 0; n < this.data.length; n++) {
    var property = this.data[n];
    let sliceAngle = 2 * Math.PI * property.value / totalValue;
    let sliceEndAngle = sliceStartAngle + sliceAngle;
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(this.pieLocationX, this.pieLocationY);
    context.arc(this.pieLocationX, this.pieLocationY, this.pieRadius, 
    sliceStartAngle, sliceEndAngle, false);
    context.fill();
    context.stroke();
    context.closePath();
    sliceStartAngle = sliceEndAngle
}
```

In the second example, my code is nearly identical, except that I am using a forEach method instead of a for loop:

```
let sliceStartAngle = 0;
data.forEach(function(property) {
    let sliceAngle = 2 * Math.PI * property.value / totalValue;
    let sliceEndAngle = sliceStartAngle + sliceAngle;
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(this.pieLocationX, this.pieLocationY);
    context.arc(this.pieLocationX, this.pieLocationY, this.pieRadius, 
    sliceStartAngle, sliceEndAngle, false);
    context.fill();
    context.closePath();
    sliceStartAngle += sliceEndAngle
});
```

I would expect the forEach method to loop through my data array the same way that `for` does. However, I am wondering why, in the case of drawing on the canvas, I am getting a different result when I use the forEach method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its the "this" scope thing in the forEach in the native Js
Quick solution for you would be:

```
let _this = this;
let sliceStartAngle = 0;
data.forEach(function(property) {
  let sliceAngle = 2 * Math.PI * property.value / totalValue;
  let sliceEndAngle = sliceStartAngle + sliceAngle;
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(_this.pieLocationX, _this.pieLocationY);
  context.arc(_this.pieLocationX, _this.pieLocationY, _this.pieRadius, 
  sliceStartAngle, sliceEndAngle, false);
  context.fill();
  context.closePath();
  sliceStartAngle += sliceEndAngle
});
```

OR use ES6

```
let sliceStartAngle = 0;
data.forEach((property) => {
  let sliceAngle = 2 * Math.PI * property.value / totalValue;
  let sliceEndAngle = sliceStartAngle + sliceAngle;
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(this.pieLocationX, this.pieLocationY);
  context.arc(this.pieLocationX, this.pieLocationY, _this.pieRadius, 
  sliceStartAngle, sliceEndAngle, false);
  context.fill();
  context.closePath();
  sliceStartAngle += sliceEndAngle
});
```

Some extra info, the for-next loop doesnt scope the variables, the forEach is handeling a callback (what is a function) and then "this" is the scope of the function

My 2 cents on this

Comment: Thank you for the help Holger. Your solution using the arrow function worked!